# Receiving MMS works, but XML response only sometimes get sent

Tags: twilio

I have a PHP rest server that accepts MMS messages. I can accept the images just fine, but I want to send a response back, sort of a "Got your photo, thanks!" But that only sometimes gets sent.  I'm using Twilio to interface messsages to my PHP, which must store data in MySQL and then notify mobile devices of the new photo.  I can see the Twilio logs and it randomly
replies to some and not others.

Am I doing anything wrong that would make the response be delivered just a few times?

### PHP - receiveMMS.php

```
require('../twilio-twilio-php-9d8bb7d/Services/Twilio.php');

include_once 'DBConnect.php';

include_once 'gcm.php';


$account_sid = "AC...5b"; // Your Twilio account sid
$auth_token = "5e0..5"; // Your Twilio auth token

$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);

header('Content-type: text/xml');

// Create a TwiML response object - this object helps us generate an XML string
// that we will output as the respnse of this request
$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
$message = $response->message();
$message->body(' thanks for sending');
print $response;

if ( isset($_POST['NumMedia']) && $_POST['NumMedia'] > 0 ){
<snip>
   process image into DB, notify mobile devices, etc)
</snip
```

}

Comment: If you want to send a SMS message everytime you get an MMS, you might want to consider returning TwiMl to Twilio upon receiving the MMS message. Have a look at this for more information https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/your_response, or post some more details in your question.

Comment: I fixed the issue.  I was outputting some debug data that was interferring with the XML response